# Uploading pdf file from iphone

Tags: ios

i have currently working on file handling application,where i have already completed image uploading using AFNetworking with multipart selection from camera as well as gallery.
but my question is how can i select a pdf file from device[iPhone]?
I would greatly appreciate it if you kindly give me some Answer. Thank You in Advanced.

Here is my image uploading code..

```
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *man = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc]init];
    man.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];
    int i=0;
    [self dispLoaderOnView:self.view loaderText:@"Loading.."];
    for(i=0 ; i< selectedImages.count; i++)
    {
        NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation([selectedImages objectAtIndex:i]);



        AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [man POST:FileUpload parameters:@{
                                                                       @"queryid":@"37",
                                                                       @"txtFilesQuery[]":imageData,
                                                                       @"selFileType[]":self.textFieldChooseFile.text,
                                                                       }
        constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {


        [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"txtFilesQuery[]" fileName:[fileNamearray objectAtIndex:i] mimeType:@"image/png"];
                                                                       }
        success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
        {

        NSLog(@"Success: %@ ***** %@", operation.description, operation.responseString);

            if(i==selectedImages.count-1)
            {
                [self hideHUDLoader];
            }

            UIAlertView  *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"File Uploaded" message:@"Suucessfully.." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];

        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
        {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ ***** %@", operation.responseString, error);
        }];
        [op start];


    }
```

Comment: You can't browse your iphone because file system is closed. You can store pdf and text files into your document directory or Library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation([selectedImages objectAtIndex:i]);

replace this code by following line

NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[selectedImages objectAtIndex:i]];

and

[formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"txtFilesQuery[]" fileName:[fileNamearray objectAtIndex:i] mimeType:@"image/png"];

Replace this code by following

[formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"txtFilesQuery[]" fileName:[fileNamearray objectAtIndex:i] mimeType:@"application/pdf"];

may this help u.......!!!!!

let me know if it help u.

Comment: Yes i appreciate your answer ....its really help me...but my question is how can i select pdf file from device ?
i mean how to choose pdf file from device ?
Thank You.